# Python replace doesn't replace a value as I expect

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a string that has a substring that I'd like to match and replace.

```
movie.2002.german.720p.x264-msd...
```

I want to remove `x264-blblxcv`. This line doesn't work as expected.

```
title = title.replace('.x264-\S+','')
```

Comment: `str.replace` *does* work like it should (as in, it works as the documentation claims) - even if you don't understand it. Be careful with such claims against established APIs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`str.replace()` does *not* support regular expressions. You can only replace literal text with that method, and your input string does not contain the literal text `.x264-\S+`.

Use the [`re.sub()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to do what you want:

```
import re

title = re.sub(r'\.x264-\S+', '', title)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> title = 'movie.2002.german.720p.x264-msd...'
>>> re.sub(r'\.x264-\S+', '', title)
'movie.2002.german.720p'
```

Alternatively, partition on `.x264-` with [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
title = title.partition('.x264-')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) will not accept regular expressions as input. Perhaps you want [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
import re
title, pattern = "movie.2002.german.720p.x264-msd...", re.compile("\.x264-\S+")
print pattern.sub('', title) # or re.sub(pattern, '', title)
```

**Output**

```
movie.2002.german.720p
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the part starting from '.x264', you can use statement like this:

```
title=title[:title.find('.x264')]
```